# Can bitcoin-core wallet be used as the backend for a mobile wallet app?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, json-rpc, bip32-hd-wallets

my idea is to use bitcoin core and it's multi-wallet capabilities as the back-end of a mobile wallet app. The way I think this could be archieved is by creating an empty wallet with `bitcoin-cli createwallet true` and then using the `importmulti` RPC command to upload an output descriptor with an xpub.

Disregarding the privacy issues, the only other thing that worries me about this is that some wallets might cause the node to re-scan the blockchain, and since this can potentially take a while, all other clients will be basically denied their service.

I have not really tested this, but I'm pretty sure this will prevent this architecture from ever working. Am I right? or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two open source mobile wallets that already do just this:

[FullyNoded](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/fully-noded/id1436425586) for iOS, which connects to a bitcoin node via a Tor V3 Hidden Service

[Sifir](https://sifir.io/bitcoin/cyphernode) which uses the brilliant [Cyphernode](https://github.com/SatoshiPortal/cyphernode)

Answer (score 0):

> Can bitcoin-core wallet be used as the backend for a mobile wallet app?

Yes

Using one of the libraries to create app will be better approach in my opinion.

Examples:

[BitcoinJ](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj) : if using Java to create the app

[NBitcoin](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin) or [NBXplorer](https://github.com/dgarage/NBXplorer) : if using C# to create the mobile app

Comment: Cool, I understand these libraries can be used for the client-side of things. I'm just concerned about the potential DoS vector that allowing anyone to trigger re-scans on my node pose. I think this makes this architecture inviable.